# complement of an infinite union of hyperplanes

Tags: differential-topology

Hi all:

A topology problem has bothered me for quite a long time. Any idea or references is greatly appreciated.

Suppose $M$ is an infinite (possibly uncountable) union of complex hyperplanes in $C^n$.
To be specific, we write $$M=\cup H_{a}$$
where $H_a=\{z\in C^n:\ a\cdot z=0\}$.

If $M$ is a finite union, then the de Rham cohomology (with complex coefficient) of $M^c$ is generated by the 1-forms $\frac{a\cdot dz}{a\cdot z}$. This is a well-known theorem. My question is whether there is a similar theorem for an infinite union of hyperplanes. We can assume the first de Rham cohomology $H^1(M^c,\ C)$ is finite dimensional. In particular, is
$H^1(M^c,\ C)$ spanned by the 1-forms $\frac{a\cdot dz}{a\cdot z}$?

Thanks a lot!

Ron Yang

SUNY at Albany

Comment: The set $M$ may not be closed (and so $M^c$ may not be open
and thus may not have de Rham cohomology).

Comment: ...and you probably mean a *countable* union of hyperplanes?

Comment: By the way: why can we «assume that the first de Rham cohomology is finite dimensional»?

Comment: There is a well-developed theory for the case of $\textit{affine}$   hyperplanes, but I cannot recall having seen anything interesting in the infinite linear case. 